# Delete digits in Python (Regex)

Tags: python, regex, digits

I'm trying to delete all digits from a string.
However the next code deletes as well digits contained in any word, and obviously I don't want that.
I've been trying many regular expressions with no success.

Thanks!

---

```
s = "This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes 134411"
s = re.sub("\d+", "", s)
print s
```

Result:

> This must not b deletd, but the number at the end yes

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Add a space before the \d+.

```
>>> s = "This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes 134411"
>>> s = re.sub(" \d+", " ", s)
>>> s
'This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes '
```

Edit:  After looking at the comments, I decided to form a more complete answer.  I think this accounts for all the cases.

```
s = re.sub("^\d+\s|\s\d+\s|\s\d+$", " ", s)
```

Comment: What about strings such as " 3at"?

Comment: Here's another 2 cases for your unit tests: '123 should be deleted.' and 'You have been 0wn3d'

Comment: Another one re.sub("^\d+\s|\s\d+\s|\s\d+$", " ", "1 2 3 fails for me")

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
"\b\d+\b"
```

That'll match only those digits that are not part of another word.

Comment: This doesn't delete the first or last numbers for, s = s = "1234 This must not b3 delet3d, 123 but the number at the end yes 134411"

Comment: I just tested it with your string and I got the expected result. \b matches either the beginning of the string, the end, or anything that isn't a word character ([A-Za-z0-9_]). I tested it in IronPython though, don't know if there's something wrong with Python's handling of word boundaries

Comment: I haven't tried this, but could you do something like: [^\b]\d+[$\b]

Comment: sharth: that's essentially the same. \b will match at the beginning or end of the string already. It's a "null pattern" that matches "between" a word and a non-word. So re.sub(r'\b', '!', 'one two') gives "!one! !two!"

Answer (score 7):

Using `\s` isn't very good, since it doesn't handle tabs, et al. A first cut at a better solution is:

```
re.sub(r"\b\d+\b", "", s)
```

Note that the pattern is a raw string because `\b` is normally the backspace escape for strings, and we want the special word boundary regex escape instead. A slightly fancier version is:

```
re.sub(r"$\d+\W+|\b\d+\b|\W+\d+$", "", s)
```

That tries to remove leading/trailing whitespace when there are digits at the beginning/end of the string. I say "tries" because if there are multiple numbers at the end then you still have some spaces.

Answer (score 6):

To handle digit strings at the beginning of a line as well:

```
s = re.sub(r"(^|\W)\d+", "", s)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try this

```
s = "This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes 134411"
re.sub("(\s\d+)","",s)
```

result:

```
'This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes'
```

the same rule also applies to

```
s = "This must not b3 delet3d, 4566 but the number at the end yes 134411" 
re.sub("(\s\d+)","",s)
```

result:

```
'This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes'
```

Answer (score 4):

To match only pure integers in a string:

```
\b(?<![0-9-])(\d+)(?![0-9-])\b
```

It does the right thing with this, matching only everything after million:

```
max-3 cvd-19 agent-007 8-zoo 2ab c3d ef4 55g h66i jk77 
8m9n o0p2     million     0 22 333  4444
```

All of the other 8 regex answers on this page fail in various ways with that input.

The dash at the end by that first 0-9 ... [0-9-] ... preserves -007 and the dash in the second set preserves 8-.

*Or \d in place of 0-9 if you prefer*

[*at regex101*](https://regex101.com/r/BiIIHr/1)
[image]

*Can it be simplified?*

Comment: The parens around \d+ can be dropped but could be used to capture just the pure digits

Answer (score 2):

If your number is allways at the end of your strings try :

```
re.sub("\d+$", "", s)
```

otherwise, you may try

```
re.sub("(\s)\d+(\s)", "\1\2", s)
```

You can adjust the back-references to keep only one or two of the spaces (`\s` match any white separator)

Comment: \W is probably better than \s for this.

Also, a better variation would be "\b\d+\b" except that it fails to work for me!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your real situation looks like, but most of the answers look like they won't handle negative numbers or decimals,

`re.sub(r"(\b|\s+\-?|^\-?)(\d+|\d*\.\d+)\b","")`

The above should also handle things like,

"This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes -134.411"

But this is still incomplete - you probably need a more complete definition of what you can expect to find in the files you need to parse.

Edit: it's also worth noting that '\b' changes depending on the locale/character set you are using so you need to be a little careful with that.

Answer (score 1):

Non-regex solution:

```
>>> s = "This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes 134411"
>>> " ".join([x for x in s.split(" ") if not x.isdigit()])
'This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes'
```

Splits by `" "`, and checks if the chunk is a number by doing [`str().isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit), then joins them back together. More verbosely (not using a list comprehension):

```
words = s.split(" ")
non_digits = []
for word in words:
    if not word.isdigit():
        non_digits.append(word)

" ".join(non_digits)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a light-bulb moment, I tried and it works:

```
sol = re.sub(r'[~^0-9]', '', 'aas30dsa20')
```

output:

```
aasdsa
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>>s = "This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes 134411"
>>>s = re.sub(r"\d*$", "", s)
>>>s
```

"This must not b3 delet3d, but the number at the end yes "

This will remove the numericals at the end of the string.