# Delete numbers not years with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I know [how to delete extra-word numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817122/delete-digits-in-python-regex), with:

`s = re.sub("^\d+\s|\s\d+\s|\s\d+$", " ", s)`

I'm wondering whether it would be possible to perform the same action while keeping dates:

`s = "I want to delete numbers like 84 but not dates like 2015"`

In English a quick and dirty rule could be: if the number starts with 18, 19, or 20 and has length 4, don't delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match any digit sequences other than 4-digit sequences starting with `18`/`19`/`20`, you can use

```
r'\b(?!(?:18|19|20)\d{2}\b)\d+\b'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tB0qR8/1)

The regex matches:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?!(?:18|19|20)\d{2}\b)` - a negative lookahead that restricts the subsequent pattern `\d+` to only match when the no `18`, `19` or `20` are in the beginning and then followed by exactly two digits `\d{2}` (*note* you can shorten the lookahead to `(?!(?:1[89]|20)\d{2}\b)` but a lot of people usually frown upon that as readability suffers)
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

[Python code](https://ideone.com/c6BxoW):

```
p = re.compile(r'\b(?!(?:18|19|20)\d{2}\b)\d+\b')
test_str = "Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, 4 5 6 created in 2008"
print p.sub("", test_str)
```

Comment: Just thought about float values, and came up with [`\b(?!(?:18|19|20)\d{2}\b(?!\.\d))\d*\.?\d+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/tB0qR8/2).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but with `Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, 4  5  6  created in 2008` it only remove the first number (4), not 5 and 6... see: https://regex101.com/r/tB0qR8/1

Comment: with respect to your first comment, thanks a lot for this improvement.

Comment: [It works](https://regex101.com/r/tB0qR8/3) if you add `/g` flag. In Python, `re.sub` replaces all matches (no need to specify anything) by default.