# Delete numbers not dates in R (regex)

Tags: regex, r

I want to remove numbers (integers and floats) from a character vector, preserving dates:

`"I'd like to delete numbers like 84 and 0.5 but not dates like 2015"`

I would like to get:

`"I'd like to delete numbers like and but not dates like 2015"`

In English a quick and dirty rule could be: if the number starts with 18, 19, or 20 and has length 4, don't delete.

I asked the same question in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199924/delete-numbers-not-dates-in-python-regex) and the answer was very satisfying ([`\b(?!(?:18|19|20)\d{2}\b(?!\.\d))\d*\.?`](https://regex101.com/r/tB0qR8/2)).

However, when I pass the same regex to grepl in R:

`gsub("[\b(?!(?:18|19|20)\d{2}\b(?!\.\d))\d*\.?]"," ", "I'd like to delete numbers like 84 and 0.5 but not dates like 2015")`

I get:

`Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\b(?!(?:18|19|20)\d"`

Comment: Just FYI: In R `gsub`, you need to double backslashes. And you should not put all into a character class `[...]`. Also, the lookahead requires the use of `perl=T`.

Comment: replace \ with \\. @stribizhev not only for gsub.. And also don't put your regex inside `[]`.

Comment: Use [`gsub("\\b(?!(?:18|19|20)\\d{2}\\b(?!\\.\\d))\\d*\\.?\\d+\\b"," ", "I'd like to delete numbers like 84 and 0.5 but not dates like 2015", perl=T)`](https://ideone.com/nEh4Ea).

Comment: @stribizhev this is perfect thanks. if you make it an answer I'll accept it and close the thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, the main points here are:

- regex pattern should be placed outside the character class to be treated as a sequence of subpatterns and not as separate symbols inside the class
- the backslashes must be doubled in R regex patterns (since it uses C strings where `\` is used to escape entities like `\n`, `\r`, etc)
- and also you need to use `perl=T` with patterns featuring lookarounds (you are using  lookaheads in yours)

Use

```
gsub("\\b(?!(?:18|19|20)\\d{2}\\b(?!\\.\\d))\\d*\\.?\\d+\\b"," ", "I'd like to delete numbers like 84 and 0.5 but not dates like 2015", perl=T)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/nEh4Ea).

Answer (score 1):

To search and replace in R you can use:

```
gsub("\\b(?!(?:18|19|20)\\p{Nd}{2}\\b(?!\\.\\p{Nd}))\\p{Nd}*\\.?", "replacement_text_here", subject, perl=TRUE);
```