# Regex pattern to remove numeric value from words in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on pyspark dataframe and I have a column of `words` `(array<string> type)`. What should be the regex pattern to remove numeric values and numeric values from words?

```
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|id |    words                                     |
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|564|[fhbgtrj5, 345gjhg, ghth578ghu, 5897, fhrfu44]|
+---+----------------------------------------------+
```

expected output:

```
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|id |words                                         |
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|564|               [fhbgtrj, gjhg, ghthghu, fhrfu]|
+---+----------------------------------------------+
```

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete digits in Python (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817122/delete-digits-in-python-regex)

Comment: @jbflow thanks for looking into it. the references you shared certainly removes numbers but another aim is to keep alphabets from alphanumeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` together with `regexp_replace` to remove the numbers, and use `array_remove` to remove the empty entries (which comes from those entries which only consist of numbers).

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    'words', 
    F.expr("array_remove(transform(words, x -> regexp_replace(x, '[0-9]', '')), '') as words")
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+---+-------------------------------+
|id |words                          |
+---+-------------------------------+
|564|[fhbgtrj, gjhg, ghthghu, fhrfu]|
+---+-------------------------------+
```