# Removing a specific digit from a number that was specified by the user

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to make a Python program that removes specific digit from a number, example a = 12025 k = 2 result is 105, however none of the guides helped me do that, can anybody help me with that?

Comment: You forgot to show us all the things you tried :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817122/delete-digits-in-python-regex

Answer (score 1):

Conversion to string does not seem elegant.
As pseudo-code:

```
number without digit (number, digit)
    if number == digit
        0
    else if number < 10
        number
    else if number % 10 == digit
        number without digit (number / 10, digit)
    else
        number without digit (number / 10, digit) * 10 + (number % 10)
```

Where `/` is integer division, truncating the remainder, and `%` is the modulo, remainder.

So it is a matter of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert into `str` type, then remove the occurrencies, and go back to `int`

```
int(str(a).replace(str(k),''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 12025
k = 2
print(int(str(a).replace(str(k), '')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use math rather than converting to and from string you can do

```
a = 12025
k = 2

result = 0
exp = 0
while a:
    a, remainder = divmod(a, 10)
    if remainder != k:
        result = result + 10**exp * remainder
        exp += 1
```